# Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am building a spring boot application but I cannot Figure out this issue in the main class.

- **Main Class**

  ```
   package io.javabrains.coronavirustracker; 
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableScheduling
   public class CoronavirusTrackerApplication {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(CoronavirusTrackerApplication.class, args);
       }

   }
  ```
- **The Error**

> Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for the default
> constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

[image]

Please Help

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the project setup. In intelliJ, select pom.xml->Maven->Reload

Comment: Something is wrong but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: what is the version of java in pom.xml. Do you have that in your classpath?

Comment: Clear the cache of Idea IntelliJ reimport the project from scratch meaning to remote the directory `.idea` from your project...check which JDK version is used by IDEA ....Which version of IDEA IntelliJ are you using?